# Filter results by time not working mapbox

Tags: time, openstreetmap, mapbox

Please could you help me create a time filter for my website here: See this page www.livehazards.com/lightning

I've successfully managed to create a 'mag' filter see here

```
document.getElementById('filters').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var mag = e.target.value;
  var filtermag;
  if (mag === 'Mag6') {
    filtermag = ['in', 'mag', 6,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9];
  } else if (mag === 'Mag5') {
    filtermag = ['in', 'mag', 5,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9];
  } else if (mag === 'Mag4') {
    filtermag = ['in', 'mag', 4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4];
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
  map.setFilter('earthquake-layer', filtermag);
});
```

I tried to create a time filter but it is not working

```
document.getElementById('filters').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var time = e.target.value;
  var filtertime;
  if (time === '24h') {
    filtertime = ['=>', 'time', 20170120000000000];
  } else if (time === '48h') {
    filtertime = ['<=', 'time', 20170120000000000];
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
  map.setFilter('earthquake-layer', filtertime);
});
```

I am running the script from usgs website 
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php see below for time

> time Data Type Long Integer Description Time when the event occurred.
>   Times are reported in milliseconds since the epoch (
>   1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z), and do not include leap seconds. In certain
>   output formats, the date is formatted for readability.

Now I think the problem lies in the way i've formatted the time as in '20170120000000000'.....

I have no idea how to proeceed , Any ideas . Thanks

Comment: Could also be the way im querying the time "=>", could be wrong?

Comment: Anyone got some suggestions?